# rejecting argument trial is unconstitutional

Tags: phrase-meaning

The phrase "rejecting  argument trial is unconstitutional", even in a headline, sounds a bit odd to me without "that" leading the clause "trial is unconstitutional."  Does it sound odd to you too?

> 6 Republicans join Democrats in **rejecting  argument trial is unconstitutional**
> After dramatic appeals by House Democrats, the former president will be the first to undergo an impeachment trial after leaving office.

> Source: [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/senate-impeachment-trial-trump/2021/02/09/66c7ad20-6ae8-11eb-9f80-3d7646ce1bc0_story.html)

Comment: how would you do it *in less space*?

Comment: It's headlinese... cutting out everything that's not essential.

Comment: It sounds odd out of context (though mainly because of the missing articles) but not as a headline.  But if it did sound odd to someone as a headline, it would be unsurprising and not necessarily significant (since conventions for headlinese differ between English-speaking countries, for example).  I think this is a pure matter of opinion.